# Inkscape-- convert text to object, dynamic offset. Shift+Ctrl+C failed?

Tags: inkscape

I met a problem when I try to

1> convert a text line into object, apply `Path > Object to Path` (or `Shift+Ctrl+c`),

2> then appy `'Path>Dynamic offset'` (or `Ctrl+J`).

The text line (let's say "test") can be converted to path. But when I apply Dynamic offset, nothing happens. Normally I will see a tiny small rectangular on the edge of text, but this time I don't see it. Is it because I've changed somewhat default parameter set of Inkscape?

I've done it through:

1> apply text `'Path > Object to Path'`

2> Ungroup it `'Ctrl+U'.`

3> select all the single letter, apply `'Path > Combine'` (`Ctrl+K`)

Now I can apply Dynamic Offset to the text now.

Thus, any suggestions?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

first `Ctrl+K` (path combine), then `Ctrl+J` (dynamic offset) will work.

Comment: I think you could improve this answer by explaining what the original problem was: What does "Path combine", and why doesn't offset work without?